# How to insert few columns in a Table using spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I am getting some fields from **Multiple tables using joins** using a select statement(5 fields).
[image]

I have to insert these values in another Table **Table-B** which is having more columns(10 columns).
[image]

How to insert these values in the **Table_B** like Col1 to id column and Col2 in Alias and Col3 in emp_age and Col4 in occupation.

I am getting the first result of multiple joins in a dataset.

Dataset exlCompaniesDataset = sparkSession.sql("Select query with multiple inner joins");

How to get each column values from Dataset and insert it in **Table-B** ?

Comment: Hey, its always good to show what you have done.. and where you are getting issue.. with proper screen shots..You know people like me might not be able to understand your issue exactly without proper screenshot..

Comment: You have to basically match the columns of target as source data frame:
Add rest of columns as like this
df.withColumn("foobar", lit(null: String))

Comment: @Srinivas, Sorry for less data. I have updated more info now.

Comment: @shobhit How to match the columns of target as source data frame?

Answer (score 0):

You essentially need to solve 2 issues -

1. Make the initial dataframe to have the same number of columns as your target
2. Rename the columns as needed from source to target.

Below is a sample code to do this. I have shown the spark-shell output at places to make it easier to understand.

```
import scala.util.Try
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

//Input Data
val inputDF = spark.sql("SELECT '1' as Col1,'name' as Col2,'age' as Col3,'job' as Col4")
scala> inputDF.show(false)
+----+----+----+----+
|Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|1   |name|age |job |
+----+----+----+----+

//make same number of columns as needed in target
val inputColList = List("Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4","Col5","Col6","Col7","Col8","Col9","Col10")

var newDf = inputDF
//Loop and add any missing columns as Null
inputColList.foreach( fieldName => {
  if(!Try(newDf(fieldName)).isSuccess)
  newDf = newDf.withColumn(fieldName, lit(null).cast(StringType))
})

scala> newDf.show(false)
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+
|Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Col5|Col6|Col7|Col8|Col9|Col10|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+
|1   |name|age |job |null|null|null|null|null|null |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+

//Create a Source to Target Map.
val srcTgtMap = Map ("Col1"->"id","Col2"->"Alias","Col3"->"ten_id","Col4"->"occupation","Col5"->"emp__age","Col6"->"Salary","Col7"->"created_date","Col8"->"Modified_date","Col9"->"some_col1","Col10"->"col_col2" )

//Iterate to get new column names.

val colMappingList = srcTgtMap.keys.map(key => col(key).as(srcTgtMap(key))).toList
val dfRenamed = newDf.select(colMappingList: _*)

scala> dfRenamed.show(false)
+--------+--------+------+-------------+------+------------+----------+---------+---+-----+
|col_col2|emp__age|ten_id|Modified_date|Salary|created_date|occupation|some_col1|id |Alias|
+--------+--------+------+-------------+------+------------+----------+---------+---+-----+
|null    |null    |age   |null         |null  |null        |job       |null     |1  |name |
+--------+--------+------+-------------+------+------------+----------+---------+---+-----+
```

Hope that helps!!